# How to limit access to a shared ami

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to share an ami so that it can be used by a client to create their own instances through their own account.  However, I do not wish that client to be able to ssh in to the instance.  I will need to be able to ssh into the instance to be able to maintain it.  They will have ftp and www access only.  I've got the ftp and www access part working through ssh configuration.  How do I keep them out of ssh when they are starting up the instance with their own keypairs?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't *really* prevent this, if they are determined to get in, since they control the instance.

Stop instance → unmount root EBS volume  →  mount elsewhere → modify contents → unmount → remount → restart → pwn3d.

However, according to [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/building-shared-amis.html), if you don't configure the AMI to *load* their public key, it just sits there and doesn't actually work for them.

> Amazon EC2 allows users to specify a public-private key pair name when launching an instance. When a valid key pair name is provided to the RunInstances API call (or through the command line API tools), the public key (the portion of the key pair that Amazon EC2 retains on the server after a call to CreateKeyPair or ImportKeyPair) is made available to the instance through an HTTP query against the instance metadata.
>
> To log in through SSH, your AMI must retrieve the key value at boot and append it to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys (or the equivalent for any other user account on the AMI). Users can launch instances of your AMI with a key pair and log in without requiring a root password.

If you don't fetch the key and append it, as described, it doesn't appear that their key, just by virtue of being "assigned" to the instance, will actually give them any access to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally accomplish this crazy task by using this process:

1)  Login as ubuntu
2)  create a user, belongs to sudo and admin group
3)  install all my s/w under the newuser
4)  verify that new user has all required privileges
5)  chroot jail the ubuntu user to ftp access only

when the ami is transmitted to the new zone/account, the ubuntu user exists as a sudoer, but cannot ssh into the instance.  Ftp allows them to connect to the system, but they view a bare directory and cannot cd anywhere else in the system.

It's not a complete denial, but I think it will serve the purpose for this client.